# Problems with a simple if/else statement (not equal to or conditionals) - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im relatively new to Python, and I was wondering if I could get a fresh set of eyes. I have been coding a simple if/elif structure, with not !=, or conditionals inside. My goal is for it to iterate through each item in the list, determine whether or not the item is equal to one of three specified string values, and produce an error if it is not. I am not entirely sure why this code doesn't execute properly, but I would greatly appreciate any help you're willing to give!

```
if yes_or_no_further_data.lower() == 'yes' or yes_or_no_further_data.lower() =='y':
        #The following code asks the user what further information they would like to specify, and possible calculations that could be derived from this
        print('\nPlease select the letter(s) of the following information you would like to enter, spaced out: \n')
        print('\tA) Precise byproducts from the Nuclear Reaction (gives more precise energy output) \n')
        print('\tB) The total amount of energy lost \n')
        print('\tC) What your specified amount of energy could potentially power \n')
    
        userwish = input()
        ightybro = userwish.strip(',').split()
    
    
        for i in ightybro:
            if i.lower() != 'a' or i.lower() != 'b' or i.lower() != 'c':
                print(i)
                print('An error occurred, you entered an incorrect letter! Please enter the letter(s) A, B, or C (you can also enter multiple)')
                userwish = input()
                ightybro = userwish.strip().split()
                if i.lower() == 'a' or i.lower() == 'b' or i.lower() == 'c':
                    break
            else:
                continue
```

I am not entirely sure why the != "if" structure does not execute properly. When I enter "a b c" into my console, the program still goes through the if structure, despite each value equaling one of the three specified values.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The part ```if i.lower() == 'a' or i.lower() == 'b' or i.lower() == 'c': break``` looks misindented. Also, what is the output?

Comment: To make sure I understand: you want to know why, for example, `'a' != 'a' or 'a' != 'b' or 'a' != 'c'` is true? Well, what result do you expect for `False or True or True`?

Comment: Please also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change this line:

```
if i.lower() != 'a' or i.lower() != 'b' or i.lower() != 'c':
```

to this:

```
if i.lower() != 'a' and i.lower() != 'b' and i.lower() != 'c':
```

because you want to run the error message if the input is different from all 3 letters. Currently your if-statement is always True (by default the input will be different from some of the 3 letters) and the error message will never run

Comment: Ah, thank you! I didnt evaluate the logic of what I was typing. Appreciate it!

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to accept some of the answers, so that your question will leave from unanswered queue, cheers

Answer (score 0):

When you say:

```
if i.lower() != 'a' or i.lower() != 'b' or i.lower() != 'c'
```

This expression returns `True` if `i.lower() != a` or if `i.lower() != 'b'` and so on.

So, if `i == 'b'`, the first part is true, so the entire expression is `True`. It's a logical "or".

What you might have meant was probably `if i.lower not in ['a', 'b', 'c']:` instead. This only returns `True` if `i.lower()` is different from all of them. Or, in Boolean logic:

`if i.lower() != 'a' and i.lower() != 'b' and i.lower() != 'c':`

This returns `True` only if `i.lower()` is different from all of `'a', 'b', 'c'`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the or condition to and.

```
if i.lower() != 'a' and i.lower() != 'b' and i.lower() != 'c':
```

Alternatively you can do this.

```
if i.lower() not in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `any()` for simple solution

```
if any(i.lower() != 'a' and i.lower() != 'b' and i.lower() != 'c' for i in ightybro):
    #do something
```

Comment: This is not correct. you must use any, as you want to run the error if any i is different from the 3 letters